# Can I combine 1x8 DDR2 256mb ram with 1x16? If not, which is better?

Tags: memory, ddr2

I recently obtained a [Dell Dimension 5150](http://support.feelpcs.com/pc-spec/DimensionE510/specs1.htm) which appears to have had some RAM modifications too it. I found the following inside:

- 2x Samsung 256mb 1Rx16 PC2-4200U-444-12-C3
- 2x Samsung 256mb 1Rx8 PC2-4200U-444-10-A1
  (The ram is DDR2)

However, I received memory-related post errors upon an initial boot, and after testing I found one of each ofthe above to be defective. Am I able to use the remaining two and have a total of 512mb memory. If so, is it safe? If not, which one would I be better off using for a 256mb system?

Comment: You should only use memory in the same channel that is the same speed.  You have two different sets of memory that are difference.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be fine.  You won't get the benefit of the dual channel, but it will work.

For better reliability, either install them in separate channels, or, if available, change the BIOS setting so the memory is in single channel mode.

The RAM will **"work"**, but if the motherboard decides to use them in dual channel mode, it may have reliability issues.